# Bitbucket Pipelines Deployment step greyed out after 14 days due to expired artifacts

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment, bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-cloud

I have a Bitbucket Pipeline that is configured to build and then upload artifacts to the Bitbucket Download section using their official Pipe. In the deployment step i have it specfically set to not download the artifacts via the built in Pipeline but instead reach out and download it directly from Bitbucket. However, after 14 days the Deploy button becomes greyed out and the artifacts are listed as expired even though it should not be relying on the built in ones due to the download: flag being set to false. Any ideas?

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0

definitions: 
  steps:
    - step: &build-.net
        name: Build .Net 
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install zip -y
          - export CONFIGURATION=Release
          - dotnet build -c ${CONFIGURATION}
          - dotnet publish -c ${CONFIGURATION}
          - cd Web/bin/Release/net6.0/publish && zip -r ../../../../../${BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG}_${BITBUCKET_BRANCH//\//_}_${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}.zip *
        artifacts:
         - app*.zip
    - step: &upload-artifacts
        name: Upload Release Artifacts to Bitbucket
        script:
          - pipe: atlassian/bitbucket-upload-file:0.3.4
            variables:
              BITBUCKET_USERNAME: $BITBUCKET_USERNAME
              BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD: '$BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD'
              FILENAME: '${BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG}_${BITBUCKET_BRANCH//\//_}_${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}_*.zip'
    - step: &deploy
        name: Deploy to Dev
        deployment: Dev
        runs-on:
         - self.hosted
         - windows
        script:
         - Download Artifact Script
         - New-Item 'publish' -ItemType Directory
         - $BUILD_DIR = (Get-Location).Path
         - Get-ChildItem -Filter *_Backend.zip | Expand-Archive -DestinationPath publish -Force
         - msdeploy - parameters
pipelines:
  default:
    - step: *build-.net
    - step: *deploy
    - step:
        <<: *deploy
        name: Deploy to QA
        deployment: QA
        trigger: manual
    - step:
        <<: *deploy
        name: Deploy to Regression
        deployment: Regression
        trigger: manual
  branches:
    release/*:
    - step: *build-.net
    - step: *upload-artifacts
    - step:
        <<: *deploy
        name: Deploy to Production
        deployment: production
        trigger: manual
        artifacts:
         download: false
```

I can see that the zip file gets successfully uploaded to Bitbucket and when running the deploy step(Pre 14 days) can see that it is also getting downloaded properly from Bitbucket.

Comment: What you mean greyd out? The buttons are always grey for me. My guess it has to do with the fact you define artifacts property, even tho it is just to disable them

Comment: The button to deploy to the production environment is greyed out 14 days after the the pipeline is run to build the package

Comment: What if you remove the artifact property?

Comment: Then the zip file i create in the build step fails to be seen in the Bitbucket Upload Step.

Comment: `download: false` remove that

Comment: I do not want the production deployment step to download those Artifacts from the built in mechanism that's why the flag is set to false. I have a separate script that runs during deployment step that downloads those artifacts externally. If i remove the download: false flag then deployments are still greyed out after 14 days